# Use of editable macro with iterate is not working

Tags: macros, moqui

I am trying to use a dynamic id in an editable field. The text is visible but the id is not getting set properly. Here is the code snippet.

```
<section-iterate name="xyz" entry="demo" list="user">
    <widgets>
        <editable type="pre" id="${demo}" text="${demo}" transition="." />
    </widgets>
</section-iterate>
```

The browser is showing following page source:

```
<pre id="${demo}">Harry</pre>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is really for questions, please submit issues on the moqui/moqui GitHub site (note that this has recently changed from jonesde/moqui to moqui/moqui to be under an organization instead of my personal account): https://github.com/moqui/moqui/issues

Answer (score 0):

In previous releases the editable.@id attribute was not an expanded string, but it is now. The section-iterate also populates a field that will be automatically appended to each ID, so with the latest code in the GitHub repository just use something like id="DemoEditable" and a numeric suffix to make it unique will be added automatically.